# Linq Join 2 tables, the column names are different but the values in the column are the same in both tables

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq

Here, I have 2 tables "enrollcustomers" and "enrollcustomersSS". I am using a value dealCap to query the tables and getting value back, but in these two tables the column names are different, how can I join them or may be I do not need to join them, all I need are the values in the select statement. I am getting an error:

> "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.type inference failed in the call to join"

I would appreciate the help.

```
int dealCap = 123;

DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

var a = from p in db.enrollcustomers
        join o in db.EnrollCustomerSSes on p.DealCapID equals o.AgreementNumber
        where p.DealCapID==dealCap && o.AgreementNumber==dealCap
        select new 
        {
            p.CustName,
            p.DBA,
            o.BillingLanguage
        };
```

Comment: can you elaborate what is the problem coming?

Comment: Kind of looks to me like you're already joining the two tables with different names on the same values... what's wrong?

Comment: What problem are you having? Also, you don't need `p.DealCapID == dealCap && o.AgreementNumber == dealCap`.  Either one of those will suffice since you are joining them together on those fields.

Comment: Sorry, I am getting an error on join part where it says "The name of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect."

Comment: The part `&& o.AgreementNumber==dealCap` is clearly not needed, you made already the inner join, which filters the rows from o, that have o.AgreementNumber == p.DealCapID.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your model and in your database the type of:

`enrollcustomer.DealCapID`

and

`EnrollCustomerSS.AgreementNumber`

probably one is `string` and one is `int`. They must have the same type.

It is good habit to have the same name for the foreign key and the primary key (so it should be `EnrollCustomerSS.DealCapID`). But here the different names of FK and PK are not the reason why you get that error.

As I wrote in the comment: The part `&& o.AgreementNumber==dealCap` is clearly not needed, you made already the inner join, which filters the rows from o, that have `o.AgreementNumber == p.DealCapID`.

If you cannot change the model, you can use the following statement:

```
var a = from p in db.enrollcustomers
        join o in db.EnrollCustomerSSes on new { dealCap = (int)p.DealCapID } equals new { dealCap = int.Parse(o.AgreementNumber) } 
        where p.DealCapID == dealCap 
        select new
        {
            p.CustName,
            p.DBA,
            o.BillingLanguage
        };
```

or convert both types to String in the join.

```
join o in db.EnrollCustomerSSes on new { dealCap = p.DealCapID.ToString() } equals new { dealCap = o.AgreementNumber.ToString() }
```